# Wordpress multisite - How to retrieve all user roles in each site in the network

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a wordpress mutisite, and I have a duplicate user in two sites with two different roles, when I tried to costmize the return of wp/v2/users endpoint to return the users with the roles, what I got was an array with only one role.

This is how I get the roles:

```
 get_userdata($userId)->roles
```

And the response is:

```
"role": [
"author"
]
```

Does any one have an Idea how to retrieve all user roles in each site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through multiple blogs:

```
$roles = [];

foreach (get_sites() as $blog){
    switch_to_blog($blog->blog_id);
    $roles = array_merge($roles, get_userdata($userId)->roles) 
}

restore_current_blog();
```